# Dhcp service with Router in vlan in cisco

Tags: cisco

I need to know how to configure a router to be a DHCP service in a VLAN network. I don't have a project to share rn but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a commands to use for your project:

**Add Vlan**

```
enable
conf t
vlan 10
name didattica
exit
```

**Show table with Vlans**

```
show vlan brief
```

**Vlan access mode**

```
enable
conf t
interface fastethernet 0/1
switchport access vlan 10
exit
```

**Vlan trunk mode**

```
enable
conf t
interface fastethernet 0/1
shutdown
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan none
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 10
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 20
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 30
no shutdown
exit
```

**Show table with trunk**

```
show interface trunk
```

**Router on a stick**

```
enable
configure terminal
interface fastethernet 0/0
no shutdown
exit

interface fastethernet 0/0.10
encapsulation dot1Q 10
ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
exit
```

**Show router table**

```
show ip route
```

**dhcp service with router**

```
enable
conf t
ip dhcp pool lan10
network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.10.254
exit
```

**router between server dhcp (client side)**

```
enable
conf t
interface fastethernet 0/0 (client side)
ip helper-address 192.168.1.3 (ip server)
```